# Error in connection with database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I’m installed oracle 11g R2 in my system. But when I connect to the database in sql developer it shows the error as following:

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 20

I know it was due to the incorrect CLASSPATH for oracle

My CLASSPATH for oracle and java are:

```
E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jlib\orai18n.jar.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product     \11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdc6_g.jar.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0  \dbhome_1\BIN.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin.;C:\Users\JamesPJ\Documents.;E:  \app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jlib.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\jdbc\lib\orai18n.jar.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\jdbc\lib\ocrs12.jar
```

I don’t know those variables are correct or not. 
If any one know the solution for it, please answer me….
Thanks in advance….

Comment: You should post the connection url. Actually, your driver is found, but the host/port you are connecting to are unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace all found `.;` in your CLASSPATH with `;` and eleminate whitespaces such as in:

```
E:  \app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib
```

then try again, your classpath doesnt look normal now.

Comment: hello sir, It was now showing same error message as following                                                                An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
     The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
     Vendor code 20